# Converting 9 digit string to number and adding comma

Tags: ssis

I need to convert my "Column1" to string numbers to value numbers.
The input is a 9 lenght string like 000011500 or 000002151 or 000000000.
The result should be 115,00 - 21,51 - 0

So first of all I used this Expression with derived column to remove the left zeros:
(DT_WSTR,50)(DT_I8)[Column1]

So my output was 11500,  2151, 0.
Now I want to put comma's from right to the second number.

I was trying to use the following expression with derived column: LEFT([COLUMN1], LEN([COLUMN1]-2)+
"," + RIGHT([COLUMN1],2)
However I am keep getting errors.

Could you please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just convert it to a decimal and divide by 100?

e.g.

```
 ((DT_DECIMAL, 2) "000002151") / 100
```

Comment: I just got this working, COLUMN1 == "0" ? "0" : LEFT(COLUMN1,LEN(COLUMN1) - 2 < 0 ? 0 : LEN(COLUMN1) - 2) + "," + RIGHT(COLUMN1,2). But your solution is better I think! Thank you.